# re-using the variable in a function in a class in python

Tags: python

I will try to explain the problem I am facing with a small piece of code:

```
class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.csv","*.processing", "*.transforming","*.loading"]

    def process(self, event):
        eventFileName = event.src_path
        eventType = event.event_type
        if eventType == 'moved':
            eventFileName = event.dest_path
        fileNameWithPath, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(eventFileName)

        if fileExtension == '.processing': 
            # Here some function is called to do something, and then appends ".loading" to the file name
            testVariable = 75.3
        if fileExtension == '.loading':
            print testVariable
    def on_moved(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path='.')
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

When I try to do the above I am getting this error: `global name 'testVariable' is not defined` which kinda makes sense but how do I make the above work? I tried to define "testVariable" globally and initiated to 0 and tried using it the way I showed in above code but it did not work as well.
I also tried initiating testVariable as `testVariable=0` inside the class (right after "patterns = ....." line but I got this error: `local variable "testVariable" referenced before assignment` pointing towards `print testVariable`. So that didnot work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"(...) how do I make the above work?"*

By defining `testVariable` outside your conditional statements. E.g. here:

```
def process(self, event):
    eventFileName = event.src_path
    testVariable = 0
    ...
```

This will make it available within the `process` function. If you want it to be available throughout the class, you can define it here:

```
class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.csv","*.processing", "*.transforming","*.loading"]
    testVariable = 0
```

But then you have to access it via the `self` object within functions like so:

```
def process(self, event):
    ...
    if fileExtension == '.processing': 
        # Here some function is called to do something, and then appends ".loading" to the file name
        self.testVariable = 75.3
```

Comment: I tried the second approach before I posted the question (apologies for not putting that information in the question. Just updated it) and it generated: `local variable 'testVariable' referenced before assignment` error

first approach looks like working. I will test my code out

Comment: Works :-) On a side note, I tried the `self` before posting the question but I did something stupid. But thanks, I see my mistake in the code now.

Comment: Nice. Which version is best depends on your requirements. If you need to access `testVariable` from outside the class, you'll have to make it a class variable so you can do `handler = MyHandler(arguments); handler.testVariable` but if you only need it in the `process` function, that's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

testVariable only exists if you have the extension ".processing". If it's ".loading", the program tries to print a variable that hasn't been made to exist.

If statements do not create a garbage collecting scope in Python, so you don't have to "declare" it outside, so long as somewhere in your if-tree, tesVariable gets a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def process(self, event):
    def extension():
        eventFileName = event.src_path
        eventType = event.event_type
        if eventType == 'moved':
            eventFileName = event.dest_path
        return os.path.splitext(eventFileName)[1]

    if extension() == '.processing': 
        ...
    if extension() == '.loading':
        ...
```